# How to get the data into excel file using Apache POI in Java from Database

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a table, from that table I'm retrieving the data into a list. Now I need to fill that data into an excel file using Apache POI in java. see the below image

[image]

Like the above image i need to fill the data into excel file

Now my problem is how fill that data into excel file.
I was tried some code, but its not working for me.

Here is my code.

```
    ReportUtils rutils = new ReportUtils();
            List<CreateJobOrderBean>  list = rutils.getDailyreports(year); 
            int r = 10;
            int c = 0;
            for(int i=1; i<list.size();i++){
                row=spreadsheet.createRow(r); 

                cell1 = row.createCell(c);

                cell1.setCellValue(list.get(i).getSno());
                if(list.get(i).getJobCreatesOn() != null){
                    cell1.setCellValue(list.get(i).getJobCreatesOnasString());
                }
                if(list.get(i).getSurveydate() != null){
                    cell1.setCellValue(list.get(i).getSurveydateasString());
                }

                cell1.setCellValue(list.get(i).getQsemail());
                cell1.setCellValue(list.get(i).getLocation());
                cell1.setCellValue(list.get(i).getNatureofcase());
                if(list.get(i).getDol() != null){
                    cell1.setCellValue(list.get(i).getDolOnasString());
                }

                cell1.setCellValue(list.get(i).getPolicyinfo());
                cell1.setCellValue(list.get(i).getSuminsured());
                cell1.setCellValue(list.get(i).getAdjusterco());
                cell1.setCellValue(list.get(i).getAdjustername());
                cell1.setCellValue(list.get(i).getRemarks());

                style2 = workbook.createCellStyle();
                style2.setAlignment(XSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
                style2.setVerticalAlignment(XSSFCellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
                cell1.setCellStyle(style2);
                font = workbook.createFont();//Create font
                spreadsheet.setColumnWidth(c,8000);
                font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 14);
                style2.setFont(font);
                font.setColor(HSSFColor.RED.index);
                font.setBold(true);
                style2.setFont(font);
            }
```

The above code is working fine, but the data not inserting into the corresponding cells.

Comment: you might think about stopping writing boilerplate code by switching to MemPOI lib https://github.com/firegloves/MemPOI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You insert/overwrite all data in the same cell (cell1). Instead, you have to create a new cell per column:

```
            row=spreadsheet.createRow(r); 
            cell1 = row.createCell(c);
            cell1.setCellValue(list.get(i).getSno());
            cell1 = row.createCell(++c); // or however you want to track the column index
            cell1.setCellValue(list.get(i).getQsemail());
            cell1 = row.createCell(++c);
            ... and so on
```

As a matter of style: I'd rather not reuse the cell1 variable in reality. Declare them on the fly, that makes the code clearer:

```
            Cell cell1 = row.createCell(c);
            cell1.setCellValue(list.get(i).getSno());
            Cell cell2 = row.createCell(++c);
            cell2.setCellValue(list.get(i).getQsemail());
            Cell cell3 = row.createCell(++c);
            ...
```

Note that you'll have to reset the c variable for the column index in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: According your code, you are creating each and every cell. So, you know the no.of cells which you need to create right. Then why we need to take 'c' increment , instead of that we can take static numbers like 1,2,3.... right.

Comment: Yes, using fixed indexes is perfectly OK here. Using a variable and counting it up has the advantage, that you do not have to change all indexes when you insert a column later on in development.

Comment: Yes i did as you said. Its working, but I think we no need to write Cell reference multiple times right. Thank you so much.@mtj

Comment: The creation of multiple cell objects with different column values is the essence of the answer. It will not work without that.

Comment: Its working for me. I'm using only one Cell reference@mtj

Comment: In fact: with every call to row.createCell, you create a new cell reference. You simply overwrite the same variable so that the previous reference is "gone" for you (but the row object still has it internally, so the sheet works) and instead you access the new reference by the same variable name. (Learning the difference will save you a lot of headaches in the future ;-))

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment c values after inserting one cell values.